# Java client hangs when kerberos ticket expires

Tags: java, kerberos

We have implemented Kerberos java client and it is working fine. However when the kerberos ticket expires Java client application is asking for username in the console which in turn makes application hanging. In tools like SoapUI we observed the system throws Unauthorized  error when Kerberos ticket expired. We want to implement similar behaviour that is if Kerberos ticket expires Unauthorized error should be thrown instead of waiting for user input for credentials. Please help.

Setting up client system for Kerberos testing
Step 1: Add key to windows registry:
item    value
key hkey_local_machine\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\kerberos
value name  allowtgtsessionkey
value type  reg_dword
value   0x01

Step 2: Add a java system property in ClientKerberosAuthentication.java main class:
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");

Step 3: Get a ticket granting ticket (tgt):
Run the kinit utility to get a ticket-granting ticket. you can find this utility inthe /jre/bin directory.
For example:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\kinit spnuser7
Password : test@123

ClientKerberosAuthentication.java

```
public class ClientKerberosAuthentication { 
    public static Credentials getCredentials() {

            return new NTCredentials("", "", "desktop.test.com", "test.com");

}   
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory());
        Credentials use_jaas_creds = getCredentials();
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1, null),
                use_jaas_creds);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://kerbserver7.com/kerbservice/Service1.svc?wsdl");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");            
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. Did you use JAAS?

Comment: @KevinO, I have updated with more details. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is a lack of a jaas configuration file. There should be a setting for `java.security.auth.login.config`. In the absence of a defined jaas.conf file, the `doNotPompt` setting is false (indicating it will prompt). This matches the behavior described in the OP's observation of a prompt.

The solution is to create a jaas configuration file and specify said file using the aforementioned property. In said jaas.conf file, set `doNotPrompt=true`.

Example:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  useTicketCache=true
  renewTGT=true
  doNotPrompt=true
  useKeyTab=false
  storeKey=true
  debug=true
  ;
};
```

The primary discussion is in the JavaDocs at [Krb5LoginModule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.html)

There is some additional information here: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/special/krb5winguide-2/raw_files/new/kwin

Comment: @Arul, glad it helped. If appropriate, please consider accepting the answer to help future people more easily find this information. Cheers!